# Difference between Restrictions.and() & Restrictions.conjuction() in Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate framework. Can somebody please help me with the
difference between these two methods as these two perform **AND** operation. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have effectively the same meaning with the only caveat that `Restriction.and()` performs the `and` operation of 2 expressions.  `Restriction.conjuction()` of any number of expressions.